# Is this BPM or something else?

Tags: java, business-process-management

When the user A start a business in our system(j2ee web app),he fill a form then he can submit to another user B who will agree or not, user B agreed and submit to user C ...

if such scenario is not BPM, then what is it?

is there any open-source framework can help to do it ?

sorry for my bad english :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a buisness process involving humans, so have a look at BPEL4People and WS-HumanTask.

[Ode](http://ode.apache.org/) might be an interesting Open Source frameworks therefore.

Answer (score 2):

BPM sounds overkill for this scenario.

What you're describing can be implemented by using database updates for different users.

Example: user A submits a form, he can decide if it will be submitted to user B. If A does use this feature, then you do a table update that puts that process in "pending" mode and notifies user B that he must agree. And so on...

This is oversimplified, but I hope you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a scenario of BPM. Within the Business Process Management you can see this kind of interactions (a sequence of human activities, it's a business process). [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/info/bpm/what-is-bpm/) is a good introduction of BPM. If what you want is to develop a framework for your processes in a upper level, you may want to take an overview of [bizagi](http://www.bizagi.com/index.php).